# How do I add create Menu to my Facebook Bot using the Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-messenger

I've a sample bot using Microsoft's .NET Bot framework.

I would like to create a menu to Facebook messenger.

What text do I need to append and how to catch the option that the user selected?

This is what I have right now:

```
strReplyMessage.Append($"Hello, I am **TestBot** Bot");
strReplyMessage.Append($"\n");
strReplyMessage.Append($"You can say anything");
strReplyMessage.Append($"\n");
strReplyMessage.Append($"to me and I will repeat it back");
strReplyMessage.Append($"\n\n");
strReplyMessage.Append($"What is your name?");
```

Any clue?

Comment: Have you considered using a [PromptChoice dialog](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dc/df9/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_dialogs_1_1_prompt_dialog_1_1_prompt_choice.html)?

Comment: Do you know how can I use it? I dont see a sample in the documentation

Comment: Yeah, there's not much on it. SHouldn't be too hard though, you pass a style and a list of optioms..

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/86ebba09bfe5ccfdbbd66eaf9c7d19fa9bb239d1/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs/Dialogs/RootDialog.cs#L38) you will find an example on how to use a PromptChoice.

I pasted the below for your convenience.

**How to call it**

```
PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.OnOptionSelected, new List<string>() { FlightsOption, HotelsOption }, "Are you looking for a flight or a hotel?", "Not a valid option", 3);
```

**How to get the selected option**

```
        private async Task OnOptionSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
        {
            try
            {
                string optionSelected = await result;

                switch (optionSelected)
                {
                    case FlightsOption:
                        context.Call(new FlightsDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                        break;

                    case HotelsOption:
                        context.Call(new HotelsDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (TooManyAttemptsException ex)
            {
                await context.PostAsync($"Ooops! Too many attemps :(. But don't worry, I'm handling that exception and you can try again!");

                context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Im trying to add Prompt Dialog inside my public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostTest([FromBody]Activity activity), but I dont know how to get context. Any clue?

Comment: do it on a dialog, not in the controller. Check https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs for some basic guidance around dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you can adding a [KeyboardCard](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d1/daa/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_connector_ex_1_1_keyboard_card.html).

> KeyboardCard (string text, IList< CardAction > buttons)

Parameters

- text  The keyboard text.
- buttons    The buttons in keyboard.